# why hair particle looks different in render vs viewport shading?

Tags: particles, hair

I'm trying to render a makeup brush model, it looks ok in viewport shading

[image]

but when rendering it comes out like this
[image]

What am I doing wrong? It's interpolated hair particles and the display amount is the same as the render amount. Also, notice how hairs going out of the mesh and shading looks different.

[File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1POOkh8BCZWU6i9wnXBPRwiUbxBokHkfv/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Pls provide blend file so we can check your settings because you didn’t show us your settings

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1POOkh8BCZWU6i9wnXBPRwiUbxBokHkfv/view?usp=sharing @Chris

Comment: thank you for your file, i added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set your subdivision levels both the same for render and viewport.

[image]

your render value was on 2, viewport on 3

result after change:

[image]

Comment: oh, that's interesting. Because I didn't enable "Use Modifier Stack", I thought it wasn't related to the subdivision modifier. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome